# Get the actual query executed by a view

Tags: 7, views, database

I need to find out the SQL query that is executed by a certain query. Views module can show the SQL when configuring the view but apparently [the query is not the actual query that gets run in all cases](http://drupal.org/node/407854).
I am aware that the Devel module can show the database queries, but [there is no way with devel to show the actual queries except clicking the associated 'A' link with every query and there are hundreds of them](http://drupal.org/node/1190074).

How can I find out the actual query that the view executes? The view is displayed as a block.

Answer (score 40):

You have to use [hook_views_pre_execute](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7) and with Devel installed use [`dpq`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) to view the SQL String:

```
function hook_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  dpq($view->build_info['query']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It reads in the hook api page that "The query is now fully built, but it has not yet been run through db_rewrite_sql." Does this mean that there is a chance that some other hook might rewrite the sql before its run? Then I would not get the actual query in all situations.

Comment: [pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) is probably the best, but I'm not sure the query will be very much different in most cases.

Comment: I actually think there's a bug in Views in some cases, I've just posted an issue http://drupal.org/node/1845772

Comment: $view->build_info['query'] appears to be the same query Views displays if you enable SQL Query output in Views settings.

Comment: This is useless. Example

SELECT users.uid AS uid, users.created AS users_created, users.language AS users_language, users.mail AS users_mail, users.name AS users_name, 'user' AS field_data_field_first_name_user_entity_type, 'user' AS field_data_field_last_name_user_entity_type, 'user' AS field_data_field_date_of_birth_user_entity_type
FROM 
{users} users
WHERE (( (users.status <> '0') AND (users.created > 1441641600) ))
ORDER BY users_created DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

I have "field_data_field_first_name_user_entity_type" which is user field and in doesnt give proper results without alterations.

Answer (score 6):

No need for patches or hooks. Just use the following code.

```php
// Run the view.
$view = views_get_view('frontpage');
$view->set_display('page');
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();

/* Magic Below Here */
// Get query from the view.
$query = $view->query->query();

// Format SelectQueryInterface into a string.
$string = (string) $query;

// Replace arguments.
$arguments = $query->arguments();
if (!empty($arguments) && is_array($arguments)) {
  foreach ($arguments as $placeholder => &$value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
      $value = "'$value'";
    }
  }
  $string = strtr($string, $arguments);
}

// Format the query string for more readable output.
$string = str_replace(array(' {', "\n{"), ' ', $string);
$string = str_replace(array('} ', "}\n"), ' AS ', $string);
$string = str_replace(', ', ",\n  ", $string);
$string = str_replace(' AND ', "\n  AND ", $string);
$string = str_replace(' ON ', "\n  ON ", $string);
$string = str_replace('SELECT ', "SELECT\n  ", $string);
$string = str_replace('ORDER BY ', "ORDER BY\n  ", $string);

// echo $string;
echo str_replace('  ', '&nbsp;&nbsp;', nl2br($string));
```

Its output is the following.

```sql
SELECT
  node.sticky AS node_sticky,
  node.created AS node_created,
  node.nid AS nid,
  'frontpage:page' AS view_name
FROM  node AS node
WHERE (( (node.promote <> 0)
  AND (node.status = 1) ))
ORDER BY
  node_sticky DESC,
  node_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function hook_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'XYZ') {
    $query = (string)$view->build_info['query'];
    echo $query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//Get The Results by View Name and Contextual Filter nid here

```
    $viewr = views_get_view('your_view_display');
    $args[] = $myarg;
    $display_id = 'default';
    $viewr->set_arguments($args);
    $viewr->set_display($display_id);
    $viewr->execute();
    $view_content = $viewr->result;
```

See the doc for more reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7.x-3.x

Answer (score -1):

Get query without running view->execute. Wrapped in a function with the _fast suffix.

```php
function get_view_query_string_fast($view_name, $view_display, $pager = TRUE) {
  // Get view and set display.
  $view = views_get_view($view_name);
  $view->set_display($view_display);

  // Disable Pager.
  if (!$pager) {
    $pager = $view->display_handler->get_option('pager');
    $pager['type'] = 'none';
    $view->display_handler->set_option('pager', $pager);
  }

  // Get query object.
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->build();
  $query = $view->build_info['query'];
  $query->addMetaData('view', $view);
  $query->preExecute();

  // Get the query string, ready to run.
  $query_string = (string)$query;
  $query_string = str_replace('{', '', $query_string);
  $query_string = str_replace('}', '', $query_string);
  $query_params = $query->getArguments();
  foreach($query_params as $placeholder => $value) {
    if(!is_numeric($value)) {
      $query_string = str_replace($placeholder, "'$value'",    $query_string);
    }
    else {
      $query_string = str_replace($placeholder, $value, $query_string);
    }
  }
  return $query_string;
}
```

`$sql_a = get_view_query_string_fast('frontpage', 'page', TRUE);`

```
SELECT node.sticky AS node_sticky, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS nid, 'frontpage:page' AS view_name
FROM 
node node
WHERE (( (node.promote <> 0) AND (node.status = 1) ))
ORDER BY node_sticky DESC, node_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

`$sql_b = get_view_query_string_fast('frontpage', 'page', FALSE);`

```
SELECT node.sticky AS node_sticky, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS nid, 'frontpage:page' AS view_name
FROM 
node node
WHERE (( (node.promote <> 0) AND (node.status = 1) ))
ORDER BY node_sticky DESC, node_created DESC
```